# How can I set a timezone in the datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, timezone, datetimepicker

I'm using this datetimepicker jquery plugin: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and I didn't get it how to use timezone. 
I saw the documentation, but I couldn't find it.

What I tried to do is something like that:

```js
serviceDateTime.datetimepicker({
  lang: 'pt-BR',
  format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
  mask: true,
  step: 30,
  showTimezone: true,
  timezone: "-0200"
});
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This was difficult to find in the documentation, but you can pass `O` in `format` to tell the plugin to pass the GMT offset.

```
serviceDateTime.datetimepicker({
    lang: 'pt-BR',
    format: 'd/m/Y H:i O',
    mask: true,
    step: 30,
    showTimezone: true,
});
```

The detective work was to find

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#use_other_date_parser

Then from there https://github.com/kartik-v/php-date-formatter#features

Then follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and search page for

```
"Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours"
```

Comment: @klewis This answer was from 2019... did you try it?

Comment: @klewis is that a typo? what is dattimepicker??  The answer I've provided here is for jquery datetimepicker.   What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is simply used to give the user an interface to pick date and time.

If you're concerned about the display to be based on your timezone, see if this helps:

[Accounting for Timezone with jQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031218/accounting-for-timezone-with-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hijack the Date in Javascript to force my client to use UTC/GMT time through out and works with datetimepicker

```
var daysInMonth     = new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
var daysInWeek      = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
var daysInWeekLong  = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
var months          = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
var monthsShort     = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
var dateReg         = new RegExp("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$");
var dateTimeReg     = new RegExp("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{0,2})$");
var timeReg         = new RegExp("^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{0,2}$");

function twoDigit(d) {
   return (d < 10 ? "0" + d : "" + d);
}

Date.prototype.format = function(f) {
   var day         = twoDigit(this.getDate()); 
   var dayWeek     = daysInWeek[this.getDay()]; 
   var dayWeekLong = daysInWeekLong[this.getDay()]; 
   var month       = twoDigit(this.getMonth() + 1); 
   var yearLong    = twoDigit(this.getFullYear()); 
   var yearShort   = twoDigit(this.getFullYear().toString().substring(3,4));
   var year        = (f.indexOf("yyyy") > -1 ? yearLong: yearShort);
   var hour24      = this.getHours(); 
   var hour_am_pm  = twoDigit((hour24 > 12 ? hour24 - 12 : hour24));
   var am_pm       = (hour24 >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM");
   var hour24      = twoDigit(hour24);
   var minute      = twoDigit(this.getMinutes()); 
   var second      = twoDigit(this.getSeconds()); 
   var monthShort  = monthsShort[this.getMonth()]; 
   var monthLong   = months[this.getMonth()]; 

   var dateString  = f.replace(/month/ig, monthLong).replace(/mon/ig, monthShort).replace(/dd/ig, day).replace(/dy/ig, dayWeek).replace(/day/ig, dayWeekLong).replace(/mm/ig, month).replace(/y{2,4}/ig, year).replace(/hh24/ig, hour24).replace(/hh/ig, hour_am_pm).replace(/am_pm/ig, am_pm).replace(/mi/ig, minute).replace(/ss/ig, second);
   return dateString;
} 

var _f = function(item) {
   Date.prototype["get" + item] = Date.prototype["getUTC" + item];
   Date.prototype["set" + item] = Date.prototype["setUTC" + item];
}
var _d = ['Milliseconds', 'Seconds', 'Minutes', 'Hours', 'Date', 'Month', 'FullYear', 'Year', 'Day'];
_d.forEach(_f);

Date = class extends Date {
   constructor(...options) {
      if (options.length == 1 && options[0].constructor == Date) {
         if (!isNaN(options[0])) {
            super(options[0]);
         } else {
            super();
         }
      } else if (options.length > 0) {
         if (!isNaN(options[0])) {
            super(Date.UTC(...options));
         } else {
            super();
         }
      } else {
         super();
      }
   }
};
```