# Compare DateTime from client browser and remote server, C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datetime

Here's the scenario

I have a ASP.NET MVC website that has a form that allows client to enter an **expiry date** (using JQuery datepicker), after the client submits the form I need to check from my server if the submitted date is **before** the current date.

The problem is that the form or the `DateTime` object does not include any field that indicates what **timezone** the user is in, hence I am struggling to convert it to the same timezone the server is in, then compare.

What is a recommend approach to solving this?

Comment: UTC. ISO8601 to send.

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031218/accounting-for-timezone-with-jquery-datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide a form element that contains the offset

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="timezone" id="timezone" />
```

And set its value on page load

```
$(function () {
    $("#timezone").value(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks