# How to change the timezone for now button on datetimepicker without editing the datetimepicker jquery file directly?

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

I am trying to set timezone of datetimepicker to `DENVER's timezone` I have set `timezone: "+0600"` it shows this timezone selected when I open datetimepicker but  When I click now button it again select the timezone of my system. How Can I convert or change timezone?

```
$.ac_datepicker({ minDate: 0, showTimezone: true, timezone: "+0600" });
```

P.S : I am using datetimepicker on a `PHP` form

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031218/accounting-for-timezone-with-jquery-datepicker) does not solve my problem thats why I have asked a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accounting for Timezone with jQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031218/accounting-for-timezone-with-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: Hi @RAHULSR I no longer need this Question's answer. What should I do delete it or leave it? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you've found the answer, post your own answer! If you think it's still a question that would be useful to other people, leave it. Otherwise delete.

Comment: I think it won't be useful for others.

Comment: @Haroon can you please tell how you solved this problem?

Comment: @NileshJain I did not solve it. I used it without changing timezone at that time because my server had the denver timezone which pretty much itself solved the problem for me