# How to set specific timezone in datepicker using jquery only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datepicker

I've a field and applying datepicker on it using jQuery.

it is currently getting time from system/browser.

I want it to get time from specific time zone e.g America/new_york.

The `endDate` param is the key to set the calendar, means user should not be able to select the `date` from future. Currently it is looking like this

[image]

The code snippet is :

```
jQuery('#convo_start_date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd M yyyy',
     endDate: '+0d',
     autoclose: true,
     showButtonPanel: true, 
     todayBtn: 'linked'
    }).on('change', function () {
        jQuery('.datepicker').hide();
        jQuery('#convo_end_date').attr('value',jQuery('#convo_start_date').val());
    });
```

**Question:** Is there any way to set the default specific timezone like America/new_york to do not allow the date from future (according to this specific timezone)?

**Note:** I've tried [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/) but it is conflicting with my current work in jQuery, Is there any params datepicker library providesvto set with timezone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19031218/1267304

Comment: My suggestion is to make moment.js library work. You will eventually need to get timezone data from somewhere.

Comment: @alalp While working with moment.js it gives me error `TypeError: dbg is undefined`

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any code. At least, `moment().format()` line should work. Otherwise, my guess is, there is some other plugin which uses `moment` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery ui [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) plugin, you can set the [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) option to current date so that user can't select date from future.

You will need to do the conversion to the specific timezone. You can change the `targetTimeOffset` variable as per your requirement.

```
var d = new Date();
var targetTimeOffset  = -4*60; //desired time zone, taken as GMT-4
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() + targetTimeOffset );
```

Check Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/8w8v9/3387/ if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to get your solution.

Check the classes they provide like `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone`.

You can get the `DateTimeZone` depending on the Canonical ID defined in the Joda Time.

Please check this [link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) for API documentation.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: This answers the question for java, but not javascript.